# How to process each line a text file and do something with each line

Tags: batch-file

How to process each line a text file using batch file, and check a string contains in the current line, do something if true else do something else and continue to next line until eol.
I have a text file containing lines like this:

```
\\.\DISPLAY2|ASPEED Graphics Family(WDDM)
\\.\DISPLAY7|NVIDIA Tesla M10
\\.\DISPLAY11|NVIDIA Tesla M10
\\.\DISPLAY15|NVIDIA Tesla M10
\\.\DISPLAY3|NVIDIA Tesla M10
\\.\DISPLAY10|ASPEED11 Graphics Family(WDDM)
```

I need to get the number next to the word 'DISPLAY' if that line contains the word 'NVIDIA'
So in this example, I should get the numbers 7, 11, 15 and 3

Comment: Wish this post was formatted properly, It's hard to read the line differentiation's.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `FOR` statement to state each line of the text document as a string. Because of the format of your text document, we cant simply use `tokens=` alone to extract just the numbers.

Using `findstr /i "NVIDIA" "list.txt"` we can have the script only read lines that test positive for containing the word `NVIDIA` - Where `list.txt` is the name of your text file.

Using [syntax-replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) we can vary easily extract just the number by doing the following:

1. Removing everything before and including `DISPLAY`
2. Removing everything after and including the `|`

The number from each line will be set as the variable `!string!`.

For checking if the number exist *true*, you can use an `IF` statement inside your `FOR` statement. Example, `If "!string!"=="Number" ()`. Please keep in mind that if attempt to use `goto` inside your FOR loop, it will break the loop and exit the loop (Thus not checking new lines).

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%G in ('findstr /i "NVIDIA" "list.txt"') do (

set string=%%G
SET string=!string:*DISPLAY=%!
SET endbit=!string:*^|=%!
call set string=%%string:!endbit!=%%

If "!string!"=="7" (
    :: Do some code for 7
    echo string equals 7!
)
If "!string!"=="11" (
    :: Do some code for 11
    echo string equals 11!
)
If "!string!"=="15" (
    :: Do some code for 15
    echo string equals 15!
)
If "!string!"=="3" (
    :: Do some code for 3
    echo string equals 3!
))
```

---

Please feel free to change the script to your need's.

Comment: I tried this code and it worked too but I liked the suggestion from Compo because of less lines to write. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear whether you're wanting to work on only those lines containing `NVIDIA`.

If you do, then based on your provided information, you can try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=Yy|" %%A In (
    'FindStr /I "DISPLAY[0-9]*|NVIDIA" "File.txt" 2^>Nul') Do Echo %%A
Pause
```

If you're wanting to work on all string content, but have only provided information on what you wish to do with those lines containing `NVIDIA`, this may help:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ("File.txt"
) Do Set /P "=%%A"<Nul|FindStr /I "DISPLAY[0-9]*|NVIDIA">Nul 2>&1 &&(
    For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=Yy|" %%B In ("%%A") Do Echo %%B
)||Echo Do something else
Pause
```

The examples above use the text file name, `File.txt`, please adjust it as necessary.

Comment: This works great for my case. I want to work only on lines containing 'NVIDIA'. So the first line of code is what I was looking. You are great.

Comment: This works great for my case. I want to work only on lines containing 'NVIDIA'. So the first line of code is what I was looking. You are great.

Comment: It's good to hear; please consider marking your preferred answer as accepted by clicking on the large check mark to its left.